# Running multiple WB macros in sequence

Tags: excel, vba

I have different Workbooks each having own macro. After running a macro on the 1st workbook, the result is used to update a 2nd workbook. The 2nd workbook can now be opened to run own specific macro. The result from the 2nd WB is now used to update a 3rd WB, etc.

I need to run these macros in different workbooks in sequence. The final WB gives the final result. I can do this manually by opening each WB & run its specific macro, but I prefer to run on auto. So I have a separate WB with a macro to achieve this. But it stops after the 1st step, ie after running the 1st WB macro.

The main macro is as follows:

```
Private Sub EM()
'PR closeout
Sheets("Task").Select    'This WB call all the WBs in sequence
If Range("AB2").Value = 0 Then GoTo 10  'No error in PR Input
GoTo 20

10  Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\SPR\MPR Input.xlsm", _
    UpdateLinks:=3
Application.Run "'MPR Input.xlsm'!openInput"
Application.Run "'MPR Input.xlsm'!Finish"   'Saves & closes WB after running

    'Generate Exec pdf & xlsx reports
Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\SPR\PR Executive Summary.xlsm"
Application.Run "'PR Executive Summary.xlsm'!Finish"
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

    'COOP closeout
Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\SPR\COOP Data.xlsm", _
    UpdateLinks:=3
Application.Run "'COOP Data.xlsm'!EndMonth"
Application.Run "'COOP Data.xlsm'!EMcontd"  'Saves & closes WB after running

'COOP User files
Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\School Payroll\COOP Report.xlsm", _
    UpdateLinks:=3
Application.Run "'COOP Report.xlsm'!UserRec" 'Saves/closes WB after running

'PS update
Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\SPR\MPS.xlsm", _
    UpdateLinks:=3
Application.Run "'MPS.xlsm'!Finish"  'Saves & closes WB after running
Windows("Task.xlsm").Activate

'Clean PR input
Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\SPR\MPR Input.xlsm", _
    UpdateLinks:=3
Application.Run "'MPR Input.xlsm'!openInput"
Application.Run "'MPR Input.xlsm'!CleanCells"
Windows("Task.xlsm").Activate

GoTo 100
20  MsgBox "You cannot closeout. You must Clear the  Error(s) in PR Input"

100 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Misread this first time - let me try again.

Where is it falling down particularly?

Your first line in the code you posted states `Sheets("Task").Select`

It might be struggling to find the worksheet.

Try using `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Task").Select` Or if the sheet is only in the workbook that the macro is also in use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Task")

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't get back since. I have solved this problem by putting all the macros earlier spread across different workbooks on just one workbook (which I will call main WB). Hence the main macro will open each workbook & execute an application which is for the workbook. With this, I was able to run in auto mode. The final result looks like this:

Sub Create1TNoNm()
    If Range("AI5").Value = 0 Then GoTo 400      '1T

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="A:\School FMS\No Name Bills.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=3
Application.Run "'No Name Bills.xlsm'!ThisWorkbook.OBills"
Sheets("DashBoard").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Sheets("Old").Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


If Range("AJ10").Value = 0 Then GoTo 70      'Nur


If Range("BJ4").Value = 0 Then GoTo 20
Application.Run "'No Name Bills.xlsm'!NoNm1TRec"


20  If Range("BJ5").Value = 0 Then GoTo 30
Windows("No Name Bills.xlsm").Activate
Application.Run "'No Name Bills.xlsm'!NoNm1TPrep"


30  If Range("BJ6").Value = 0 Then GoTo 40
Windows("No Name Bills.xlsm").Activate
Application.Run "'No Name Bills.xlsm'!NoNm1TKG"


40  If Range("BJ7").Value = 0 Then GoTo 50
Windows("No Name Bills.xlsm").Activate
Application.Run "'No Name Bills.xlsm'!NoNm1TN1"


50  If Range("BJ8").Value = 0 Then GoTo 60
Windows("No Name Bills.xlsm").Activate
Application.Run "'No Name Bills.xlsm'!NoNm1TN2"


60  If Range("BJ9").Value = 0 Then GoTo 70
Windows("No Name Bills.xlsm").Activate
Application.Run "'No Name Bills.xlsm'!NoNm1TN3"     'End Nur




250 Windows("No Name Bills.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("DashBoard").Visible = True
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
300  MsgBox "No name Bills of Old & New students for all classes successfully generated. Click on view/print button to view/print these bills. Click OK to continue"
GoTo 500
400  MsgBox "You do not have access to this due to your selection in the Setup Form. Click OK to continue"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
500 End Sub         'End 1T
```